# How to get particular product variation quantity dynamically from the cart page in the woocommerce by variation_ID?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display quantity of product variation which added to cart and display this in the loop dynamically.

*I'm tried this PHP code:*

```
<?php
$targeted_id = $product->get_id();

// Loop through cart items
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) { 
 if( in_array( $targeted_id, array( $cart_item['product_id'],$cart_item['variation_id']) )){
  $quantity =  $cart_item['quantity'];
break; // stop the loop if product is found
 }
}
// Displaying the quantity if targeted product is in cart
if( isset( $quantity ) && $quantity > 0 ) {
  echo  '<a href="http://adel-hat.ru/cart/"><div class="qty_on_product"><i class="tb-icon tb-icon-shopping-cart on_product"></i>';
 printf( '<span class="product-cart-items">' . __("%d") . '</span>', $quantity );
  echo '</span></div></a>';
 }
?>
```

With this code I'm display all variations added to cart(because here I'm taking parent id) and it works only on page load.

> I want to get into `$tageted_id` variable variation_id dynamically when variation selector changing without page load. How I can do this?

From another hand of my problem I'm trying to get variation_id through jQuery

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery( '.variations_form' ).each( function() {
jQuery(this).on( 'found_variation', function( event, variation ) {
    console.log(variation);//all details here
    var variation_id= variation.variation_id;//selectedvariation
    console.log(variation_id);
});
});
});
</script>
```

And when I use this one i'm getting selected variation ID in console. May be is there any way to send `variation_id` variable to PHP `$tageted_id` variable dynamically without page reload?

Answer (score 0):

Now I have update functionality so you can get product selected variation id and use accordingly:

```
function find_matching_product_variation_id($product_id, $attributes)
{
    return (new \WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT())->find_matching_product_variation(
        new \WC_Product($product_id),
        $attributes
    );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'woo_find_product_in_cart' );

function woo_find_product_in_cart(){

    $targeted_product_variation_ids = array();
    $targeted_id = 4215; // product_id 

    //Loop through each item from the cart
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        //get the current product ID
        $product_id  =  $cart_item['product_id'];
        $quantity    =  $cart_item['quantity'];

        //first - check if product has variations
        if(($targeted_id == $product_id) && (isset($cart_item['variation']) && count($cart_item['variation']) > 0 ))
        {
            // Cart Product Selected Variation id
            $variation_id = find_matching_product_variation_id($product_id,$cart_item['variation']);

            //get the WooCommerce Product object by product ID
            $current_product = new  WC_Product_Variable($product_id);
            //get the variations of this product
            $variations = $current_product->get_available_variations();
            //Loop through each variation to get its title
            foreach($variations as $data)
            {
                $targeted_product_variation_ids[] = $data['variation_id'];
            }
        }else{
            $targeted_product_variation_ids[] = $product_id;
        }

        if( in_array( $variation_id, $targeted_product_variation_ids) && isset( $quantity ) && $quantity > 0){
            echo  '<a href="http://adel-hat.ru/cart/"><div class="qty_on_product"><i class="tb-icon tb-icon-shopping-cart on_product"></i>';
            printf( '<span class="product-cart-items">Variation Product Qty: ' . __("%d") . '</span>', $quantity );
            echo '</span></div></a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this one and didn't get any results.

Also tried different hooks to make it display
for example woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item which is used in my product loop template.

I'm using variation swatches and my loop card looks like this: https://ibb.co/kJFw5S1
There is example how i'm trying to display quantity in cart of particular product: https://ibb.co/SQ7zZs7

I starting to guess that I have to using javascript or Ajax...

Comment: @Nostromu : I have applied few changes and I have also tested on my cart page its working and we got qty properly. so try this one